# Office 2007 activation assistant always pop up

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

The new desktop (Win7) came with Office 2007 60-days trial preinstalled. I get a key for Office Basic (Excel,Word,Outlook) and the key get accepted.

But when i run an Office program always pop up the activation assistant for the Offce parts i have no key i do not want access, publisher, etc.

Any way to get the activation assistent stop to pop up on Office start ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Custom installation and install only the basic edition (w/o Access,PP etc), and not the Trial of Office.

Firstly - you need to uninstall everything associated with Office and the Activation Wizard and start new again using the custom install 
option and following what I posted above.